Movie name - A movie 1990 - 2000 where the devil visits village
Release date: 
Should be between 1990 and 2000.
Production: 
American (Hollywood).
Genre:
Thriller and Drama Like, not horror.
Popularity:
It was a "mainstream" movie, I guess quite successful.
Actors: 
I only remember there were some big names on it, don't know which, was young when i saw it. The "devil" and the protagonist were played by famous actors.
Story:
The devil visits a village not sure why he arrives there. The story involves a church, burning houses, earthquakes, a preacher and a hero. Showdown outside of church.

Story is still a king factor for movie identifications; you need to give more information on the story to make this answerable. What is the main story? What are the main points of conflicts? How does the story end? Are there any special scenes you remember?
